# Django does's recognize variable in img src(template)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to use a loop for listing my categories in template and django doesn't recognize the variable as a variable(I think so). And yes all the static files I need are in their folder.
Here is my view:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('useractions/home.html', {
            'ann' : Announcement.objects.all().order_by('-creation_date')[:3],
            'categories' : ['Garden', 'Moving','Cleaning', 'Babysitting', 'Cooking', 'Others']
       })
    else:
        return render(request, 'basicpages/index.html')
```

And my for in templates:

```
{% for kind in categories %}
                <li id="cat1" style="background-image: url({% static "images/categories/{{ kind }}-background.jpg" %});">
                    <a href=''>
                        <span class="cbp-ig-icon"><img src="{% static "images/categories/{{ kind }}-icon.png" %}"></span>
                        <h3 class="cbp-ig-title">{{ kind }}</h3>
                        <span class="cbp-ig-category"> Dă click aici pentru mai multe</span>
        </a>
                </li>
{% endfor %}
```

In the shell I see something like this:

```
[09/Apr/2016 16:16:54] "GET /static/images/categories/%7B%7B%20kind%20%7D%7D-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1837
[09/Apr/2016 16:16:55] "GET /static/images/categories/%7B%7B%20kind%20%7D%7D-background.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1855
```

Comment: try using `"/images/category/{{ kind }}-background.jpg"`

Comment: I get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/categories/'%}{{ kind }}-icon.png">
```

Comment: No, I get just this : " /static/images/categories/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1760"

Comment: the edited version should work if for example "127.0.0.1/static/images/categories/Garden-icon.png" exists.

Comment: Well /static/images/categories/Garden-icon.png is not a url, it is a location, a photo, and the photo does exist

Comment: sure. still it should be directly accessible via a browser when the server is running. This is to test if your static variable is properly set or not.

Comment: Yes, the url returns me the image.